# Closing jquery modal window conditionally from ASP.net code-behind

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, colorbox

I have an ASP.net page with a link to open a jquery-based modal window (that uses colobox jquery plugin). The content of that window in loaded from another aspx file (it loads an iframe). I want to close that window when the user presses an asp:button and if some condition in my code-behind went well.

I tried many ways to close that window from code-behind like these ways:

```
Page.RegisterStartupScript("X", @"$(this).dialog('close');");

Page.RegisterStartupScript("X", @"var win = window.open('','_self'); win.close();");

btnDone.Attributes.Add("onclick", @"var win = window.open('','_self'); win.close();");

btnDone.Attributes.Add("onclick", @"window.open('../px/nsk.aspx', '_self', null); window.close(); ");

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>");
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("self.close();");
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</SCRIPT>");
```

but non of them can close that modal window. I'm testing on latest version of firefox.
the code behind can be supposed as sth like this:

```
    // do some database works
if (condition)
{
   // close this modal window
}
```

I also tried methods from jquery but none of them were a success.
Can you please telling me how can I close this window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seams to be solved this way:

```
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), 
        "CloseKey", "parent.$.colorbox.close();", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers given provide specifics; this 'answer' attempts to be more conceptual/consultative.

**Closing the Window**

Closing the colorbox window is done on the client side. Both @KennyZ and @Farshid provide details on how to do this.  By default, ColorBox is going to close on the press of ESC or its EXIT ui element (if used.)  It's also possible to close the box programmatically, which sounds like what you need to do.

**Where is the Close Action Invoked?**

@KennyZ proposes an Ajax call to determine if "some condition in my code-behind went well"; that presumes you cannot tolerate a full page refresh (which seems reasonable to me) but it's something for you to decide.

If the determination of "went well" can only be done on the server, then you're looking at Ajax or a full page refresh.

Alternatively, if there is a way to make the determination on the client side, you won't need to reach back to the back end at all. Just close the colorbox window using js.

If you can provide more details about what the action is that controls closing/not closing the ColorBox window, maybe the community can help even more.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery dialog with a div instead of an iframe.

Then you can use an Ajax post to run the serverside code and look at the results to decide what to do with the dialog.

Declare the dialog:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#MyDialog").dialog(
            {
                bgiframe: true,
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                width: 800,
                position: ['center', 100]
            }
        );
    });
```

Populate the dialog and open it:

```
    $('#OpenMyDialog').click(function () {
        $.post($('url_for_dialog_contents'), function (data) {
            $("#MyDialog").empty();
            $("#MyDialog").append(data);
        }, null, "html");
        $('#MyDialog').dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
```

Submit the dialog:

```
    $('#SubmitMyDialog').click(function () {
        $.post($('url_for_dialog_action'), function (data) {
            if (data.success == true) { $('#MyDialog').dialog('close'); }
        }, null, "json");
    });
```

I'm sure you'll need a lot more code in the submit dialog, but this is the general idea.

Comment: Dear Kenny, Thanks but your solution requires that I change everything. I do not want to make my parent page heavier to load than what it currently is. However Thanks for your alternate solution.